# old URL contains specific string redirect to specific URL 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-search-console

I've got some troubles with redirecting. Well, it works, but I got problems with the Google webmaster, it can't find these URLS, which is logically, because they are gone. Except I got a bunch of lines in my htaccess which covers this hassle, at least for the user itself. But Google has some troubles. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Kleding
RewriteRule .* /kleding/? [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} CarnavalsKleding
RewriteRule .* /kleding/? [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Verhuur
RewriteRule .* /kleding/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

There are more of thse kinds of lines. It covers all the old URLs and redirects the to the new one. Only Google can't comprehend the redirect, it keeps stating that the URL is dead, which is correct, only why doesn't it see the redirect?